# Calculate the response time for JMS messages

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, jms

Working on a Java application which posts 1000 JMS messages to an EMS server using 5 threads. I have a loop which iterates 5 times, and in each loop I start a Runnable thread which posts 200 messages.

How do I calculate the response time each message takes? And the response time per thread(200 messages)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use currentTimeMillis method and count the time this way:

```
    long time1=System.currentTimeMillis();

    //Send 200 JMS Msg loop        
        long timeIntern1=System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Send a JMS Msg       
        long timeIntern2=System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time in millis last JMS Msg: "+(timeIntern2-timeIntern1));

    long time2=System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Total time in millis: "+(time2-time1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Date.getTime() method:

```
import java.util.Date;

static long stamp()
{
    return new Date().getTime();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    long start = stamp();
    //Do whatever
    Thread.sleep(5_124);
    long end = stamp();
    System.out.println("Took " + (end - start) + " milliseconds.");
}
```

Outputs:

```
 Took 5124 milliseconds.
```